# How to get tabbar click event without tabbarcontroller in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to implement tabbar in my 2nd view.
I am able to place tabbar with 5 items on it. I know to handle those click events , i have to use tabbarcontroller.

My question is , taking tabbar on view,
 How to call each item selected method without `tabbarcontroller`?
(My assumption is that `tabbar` is an object like button , and we can write a click method for that programmatically. So without Tab Controller also, we can access selected item method )
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want to use tabbarcontroller, then its always better to use Segmented Control.
It has similar kind of operations & its also simple to use. Use need to just create multiple uiviews on view & just play Hide-n-seek with them.  If you want I have some code. Will paste here, if you want.

Comment: As tabbarcontroller contains tabbar as object, suppose i m only using tabbar directly from library and i dnt wanna use tabbarcontroller.Then that will also be visible on ui. Now , what i want is : How to customise actions of each item selected event without using tabbarcontrller. I am only using tabbar as object as we use label, button. Is it possible.?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can do it like this. (*** Note : Its not tested code)

Add `<UITabBarDelegate>` in .h file

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    if(item == firstItem)
        NSLog(@"Did Select Here”);
    else if(item == firstItem)
        NSLog(@"Did Select Here”);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `UITabbar` and define `UITabbarDelegate` in .h file and write the following code in respective view:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        UITabBarItem * newItem1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"setting.png"] tag:1];
        UITabBarItem * newItem2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"setting.png"] tag:2];
        UITabBarItem * newItem3 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Third" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"setting.png"] tag:3];

    [tabbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:newItem1,newItem2,newItem3,nil]];
        tabbar.delegate = self;
    }

    - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
        NSLog(@"Tabbar selected itm %d",item.tag);
        switch (item.tag) {
            case 1:
                //first selected
                break;
            case 2:
                //second selected
                break;
            case 3:
                //third selected
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```